# Set errorlevel in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script that will loop through each line of a text file, (each line containing a filename) check if the file exists and then runs the file and moves it.

Here is my batch script:

```
REM Loop through each line of input.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (./ready/input.txt) DO (
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO Check %%i exists, set error flag if it doesnt
  if not exist .\ready\%%i set errorlevel=2
echo return code is %errorlevel%

  ECHO Run %%i if it exists
  if errorlevel 0 call .\ready\%%i

  ECHO Move %%i to archive if no error occured 
  if errorlevel 0 copy .\ready\%%i .\archive\%mydate%_%mytime%_%%j_%%k_%%i

  ECHO Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured
  if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 >>output.txt %%i, %%j, %%k
)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I do not understand why the "if errorlevel" is not working as expected... if the file does not exist (as in this example where it does not exist) it should NOT try to run the file, it should NOT copy the file, and it should echo a 2 not a 0

**Edit 1**: I was reading another [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202895/how-to-survive-delayed-variable-expansion-in-a-dos-batch-script) regarding "delayed environment variable expansion" I am not sure if this issue is related

Comment: What happens if you do `if not "%errorlevel% == "0"`? Also, maybe don't set `errorlevel` itself: http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/07/never-set-errorlevel.html

Comment: @zero298 same thing occurs when using %errorlevel% - cant view that blog as my work is blocking it =(  also tried removing the set errorlevel did not cause any change

Comment: One other thing I, why do you have `.\file\other` why not just `file/other`

Comment: @zero298 I am just used to using .\ for going to relative subfolders in folder path - personal preference

Comment: `set errorlevel=2` <--- never change/set a system variable as it overrides the system variable.  Also, when using `%variable%` within a loop requires the use of `delayed expansion` and `!variable!` syntax instead of using `%variable%`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
DEL output.txt 2>nul
REM Loop through each line of input.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (.\ready\input.txt) DO (
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO Check %%i exists, set error flag if it doesnt
  if exist .\ready\%%i (set "errorflag=") ELSE (set errorflag=2)
CALL echo return code is %%errorflag%%

  ECHO Run %%i if it exists
  if NOT DEFINED errorflag (
   call .\ready\%%i
   ECHO Move %%i to archive if no error occured
   if errorlevel 1 (SET errorflag=3) ELSE (ECHO copy .\ready\%%i .\archive\%mydate%_%mytime%_%%j_%%k_%%i)
  )
  ECHO Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured
  if DEFINED errorflag >>output.txt ECHO %%i, %%j, %%k
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a rewritten procedure.

Note: `output.txt` is deleted at the start, else the `>>` would append to any existing file. `2>nul` suppresses error messages if the delete fails (eg. file not exist)

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the ENTIRE block is parsed and **THEN** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **AT THE TIME THE BLOCK IS PARSED** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the chnaged value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

`IF DEFINED var` is true if `var` is **CURRENTLY** defined.

`ERRORLEVEL` is a special varable name. It is set by the system, but if set by the user, the user-assigned value overrides the system value.

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **OR GREATER THAN n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray spaces at the end of a line are NOT included in the value assigned.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

I used the following `input.txt`:

```
seterr1.bat, J1, K1
seterr5.bat,J2,K2
seterr0.bat,J3 K3
seterr5.bat, J4, K4
notexist.bat, J5, K5
```

With existing files `seterr*.bat` which contain

```dos
@ECHO OFF
EXIT /b 1
```

(where the `1` in the last line determines the `errorlevel` returned)

and received the resultant output:

```
Check seterr1.bat exists, set error flag if it doesnt
return code is 
Run seterr1.bat if it exists
Move seterr1.bat to archive if no error occured
Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured

Check seterr5.bat exists, set error flag if it doesnt
return code is 
Run seterr5.bat if it exists
Move seterr5.bat to archive if no error occured
Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured

Check seterr0.bat exists, set error flag if it doesnt
return code is 
Run seterr0.bat if it exists
Move seterr0.bat to archive if no error occured
copy .\ready\seterr0.bat .\archive\__J3_K3_seterr0.bat
Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured

Check seterr5.bat exists, set error flag if it doesnt
return code is 
Run seterr5.bat if it exists
Move seterr5.bat to archive if no error occured
Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured

Check notexist.bat exists, set error flag if it doesnt
return code is 2
Run notexist.bat if it exists
Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occured
```

Note that the COPY is merely `ECHO`ed as I mentioned earlier.

and output.txt

```
seterr1.bat, J1, K1
seterr5.bat, J2, K2
seterr5.bat, J4, K4
notexist.bat, J5, K5
```

Comment: Is there any difference between: if exist output.txt (ECHO Y | DEL output.txt) and DEL output.txt 2>nul ?

Comment: In effect, no. The second is easier to type.

Comment: @Kairan The difference is the '2>nul` code *always* tries to delete the file, but hides the output to `stderr`.  Whereas `if exist` checks for existence first and then only proceeds if the file exists.  99% of the time there is no noticeable difference.  However, it's possible that other errors can happen besides the file not existing (like if another process has a lock on the file) -- in both scenarios the file will not be deleted, but in the `2>nul` scenario the console will suppress the error message, and in the `if exist` scenario it won't.

Answer (score 35):

`ERRORLEVEL` and `%ERRORLEVEL%` are two different variables. That means your code with `echo return code is %errorlevel%` and `if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 >>output.txt %%i, %%j, %%k` is probably wrong.

`ERRORLEVEL` is builtin and used to fetch the result of the last command. You can use it like:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO error level is 1 or more
```

`ERRORLEVEL` *cannot* be set, just like bash does not let you `set ?= ...`

`%ERRORLEVEL%` is an environmental variable. If `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set, then its used in your script when you use `%ERRORLEVEL%`. If `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not set **AND** *if* command extensions are enabled, then it *falls back* to `ERRORLEVEL`. `ERRORLEVEL` does *not* update `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

Raymond Chen has a good blog entry on it: [`ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743). Some of the content in this answer was shamelessly lifted from it.

Comment: Yours is the only answer to explicitly state that `ERRORLEVEL` _cannot_ be set. That is the key piece if information that I think everyone needs.

Comment: *ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%* is just a catchy title. It doesn't imply that there can be two different variables called `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `ERRORLEVEL`. There is already enough confusion around this, no need to add more. Also, `ERRORLEVEL` can be set, for both meanings of "set". See other answers here.

Comment: Actually, you *can* set %ERRORLEVEL%. If you want to return 1 as errorlevel at the end of a batch or command file, just write "@COPY SetErrorLevelTo1 dummy". It can be useful for example as part of a Visual Studio Pre- or PostBuild Event to cause stopping the build process.

Comment: BTW, re *just like bash does not let you `set ?= ...`* -- `set` isn't used to set variables in bash at all (it mutates either shell settings or the active command-line argument list); perhaps you were thinking csh.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like the following subroutine:

```
:return
   ECHO @exit /b %1 >ret.cmd
   CALL ret.cmd
   GOTO :eof
```

Then use it like this:

```
:Attempt
   SETLOCAL
   CALL somethingThatFails
   SET retcode=!errorlevel!
   CALL somethingThatPasses : don't care about the errorlevel here
   CALL :return !retcode!
   ENDLOCAL
   CALL :eof
```

So, the whole thing would looke something like:

test.cmd...

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

CALL :Attempt
IF !errorlevel! NEQ 0 (ECHO Attempt Failed) ELSE (ECHO Attempt succeeded!)
GOTO :eof

:Attempt
   SETLOCAL
   CALL somethingThatFails
   SET retcode=!errorlevel!
   CALL somethingThatPasses : don't care about the errorlevel here
   CALL :return %retcode%
   ENDLOCAL
   CALL :eof

:return
   ECHO @exit /b %1 >return.cmd
   CALL ret.bat
   GOTO :eof
```

somethingthatfails.cmd...

```
DIR some command that fails >nul 2>&1
```

somethingthatpasses.cmd...

```
DIR >nul 2>&1
```

The one side effect of this is a file laying around called ret.cmd.  I usually use an :end subroutine that does cleanup and would delete it.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way to set the `%errorlevel%` with a trick I learned several years ago:

```
:: force errorlevel to 1
@(call)
echo %errorlevel%
:: force errorlevel to 0
@(call )
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

The space after `call` is necessary to set the `%errorlevel%` to `0`.

**Update:** After researching this, I found a reference [here](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, when specifically setting it to 0, I like

```
ver >nul
```

ver.exe always returns 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

for me, simple use of `cmd /c exit 2` worked to set the `errorlevel` and use it locally in a batch file and even after it ended to ask for the `errorlevel` outside:

```sh
set errorlevel=2
:
cmd /c exit %errorlevel%
:
if errorlevel 3 echo 3
if errorlevel 2 echo 2
if errorlevel 1 echo 1
if errorlevel 1 echo 0
```

**Results**

```sh
>test.bat
2
1
0
>if errorlevel 2 echo 2
2
```

Comment: You should read [the answer from jww](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23423804/463115) to understand why your solution is worse. You should never set the `errorlevel` with a `SET` command

Answer (score 0):

This is designed to execute the %%i item only if it exists and follow through with checking for errors and move or log.  if the %%i item doesn't exist then it will do nothing.

```
REM Loop through each line of input.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (.\ready\input.txt) DO (
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO Check %%i exists, execute it if it does
  if exist .\ready\%%i (
    call .\ready\%%i
    ECHO Move %%i to archive if no error occured 
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        copy .\ready\%%i .\archive\%mydate%_%mytime%_%%j_%%k_%%i
      ) else (
        ECHO Copy line of text to the new output.txt file if an error occurred
        >>output.txt %%i, %%j, %%k
      )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of answers doesn't work on all cases (ie: xp, win9x...)

This line will set ERRORLEVEL to 1, works in DOS or later:

```
<nul find ""
if errorlevel 1 echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more
```

This line will set ERRORLEVEL to 0, works in DOS or later:

```
echo a |find "a" >nul
if errorlevel==0 echo No Error
```