# How to capture powershell error in batch scripts?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Currently, I'm using this script to convert a date in `yyyyMMdd` format to `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& {([datetime]::parseexact('%testDate%','yyyyMMdd',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')}"') do SET testDate=%%a
```

When I input invalid characters/date-time structure for the `%testDate%` variable, in Powershell IDE, it throws an error message, `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"`.

However, in batch scripts, it will only return an empty `testDate` variable. It also returns `errorlevel = 0`.

How do I return the error message from powershell in batch scripts?

---

**Full script**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get user's inputs
:beginning
SET /p testDate="Please enter the date in yyyyMMdd format (e.g., 20171128)" || goto beginning
if /I "%testDate%"=="t" (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& get-date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy'"') do SET testDate=%%a
) ELSE (
    if /I "%testDate%"=="yt" (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -format 'dd/MM/yyyy'"') do set testDate=%%a
    ) ELSE (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& {([datetime]::parseexact('%testDate%','yyyyMMdd',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')}"') do SET testDate=%%a
        REM Testing 
        echo !testDate!
        echo Yes!
    )
)
REM Testing 
echo !testDate!
echo !errorLevel!
pause
```

Comment: put try/catch [Batch try/catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772060/batch-file-try-catch).

[Error handling in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling)

Comment: @RanadipDutta what I want is to return the error message generated by powershell, not create my own error message when there is a problem.

Comment: Why use a batch file at all? Just write the entire script in PowerShell. Much, much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message from `[datetime]::parseexact` is being returned in multiple lines of text and causing the `set testData=%%a` to be called multiple times. You can see this by running the command separately.

eg.

```
c:\Temp> for /f "delims=" %a in ('powershell -Command "& {([datetime]::parseexact('%testDate%','yyyyMMdd',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')} "') do SET testDate=%a
```

output:

> C:\Temp> SET testDate=Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=DateTime."
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=At line:1 char:4
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=+ & {([datetime]::parseexact('Exception calling ParseExact with 3 argum ...
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
>   C:\Temp> SET testDate=

To fix this you will need to control the return message when an error is encountered.

A `try/catch` statement can be used to achieve this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get user's inputs
:beginning
SET /p testDate="Please enter the date in yyyyMMdd format (e.g., 20171128)" || goto beginning
if /I "%testDate%"=="t" (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& get-date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy'"') do SET testDate=%%a
) ELSE (
    if /I "%testDate%"=="yt" (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -format 'dd/MM/yyyy'"') do set testDate=%%a
    ) ELSE (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& {try { ([datetime]::parseexact('%testDate%','yyyyMMdd',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') } catch { return $_.Exception.Message }} "') do SET testDate=%%a
        REM Testing 
        echo !testDate!
        echo Yes!
    )
)
REM Testing 
echo !testDate!
echo !errorLevel!
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not defined testdate (echo Invalid date supplied)
```

or

```
if not defined eventdate (echo Invalid date supplied %testdate%)
```

or

```
if not defined eventdate (echo Invalid date supplied %testdate%&goto someplace)
```

depending on quite what the circumstances are. Are you sure that `testdate` is neing modified (first scenario) - I'm suspicious that actually `testdate` remains as-is and `eventdate` is simply not being set.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to show the full script. Also, what I aimed for was to output the error message from powershell process caused by invalid characters, not creating own custom messages. Sorry that I wasn't clear enough.